# Continue PHP script when file contains text

Tags: php, file-io, while-loop, fopen

I am trying to halt my php code until a certain file contains a certain text.

```
$exit = FALSE;
while (!$exit) {
        usleep(250000);
        $fname = "/var/www/file2";
        $file = fopen($fname, 'r');
        $theText = fread($file, filesize($fname));
        fclose($file);
        if (split("\n", $theText)[0] == "ready" || $dir==0) {
                $exit = TRUE;
                $file = fopen($fname, 'w');
                fclose($file);
        }
}
```

Once this file has the word "ready" on the first line, I want the script to continue(or if $dir is 0). BUT it only works if the file already contains this word when the script started. It does not work if the file has this word written to it while it is in the loop.

Is it possible that it is not actually reloading the file but instead loading a cached file? How would I fix that? Or is there something else?

Comment: Some problem with your if condition

Comment: So what exactly do you wish to do? If file is empty, you are trying to wait for the file to be written? When you run the script, file will be read in it current state, it will not wait for some future app to write to it?

Comment: What is the `$dir` set to ?

Comment: I've determined that the problem must be that python is not actually loading the altered file, but the blank file, even after it has changed. Is there any way to fix that?

It works fine when the file already has the text. I set a limit to the number of times it would loop. When I have it echo out the file contents in each loop, it remains blank even though I know the file has been written to while the loop was going.

Answer (score 1):

Use control structure **[`break;`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php)** to end `while()` loop execution.

You can read file line-by-line with **[`fgets()`](http://php.net/fgets)**.

Comment: But this is not solving the problem? OK it's better to use break; but the solution above should work as well. And fgets() is only another way to do what Stoopkid tried, because he says, that if the file still exists with "ready" in it, it works.